# Custom property setter / getter in Python

Tags: python, properties

I do have a class "Contact" where I get all fields from one contact in a customer database. The property keys are not dynamic; the can be hard-coded.
Two access the properties, I need customer getter and setter; getters do format the output, e.g. date formatting, currency,... setters as well, e.g. when you set a datetime if converts into UNIX timestamp for the database.

Also, I need these properties to be available for auto-complete in my IDE, don't like to write property names manually as I typically screw them up with typos. So I think they either need to be an attribute or a function.

The solution I found but which is lots of lines of code:

```
class Contact(Dict):

    def __init__(self, values: Dict = {}):
        self.values = values

    get_email(self):
        return self.values('email')

    set_email(self, value):
        self.values['email'] = value

    get_create_date(self):
        d = self.values.get('create_date', None)
        if d:
            return d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        else:
            return None

    set_create_date(self, value):
        self.values['create_date'] = value

    get_price(self):
        p = self.values.get('price', None)
        if d:
            return "{:,}.-".format(p)
        else:
            return None
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to have separate getters and setters, nor to store `values` rather than storing individual elements from that `dict`.

```
class Contact:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.email = values['email']
        d = values.get('create_date')
        if d is not None:
            d = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        self.create_date = d
        p = values.get('price')
        if p is not None:
            p = '{:,}.-'.format(p)
        self._price = p

    @property
    def price(self):
        return self._price
```

Your setters aren't doing any validation, so you can assign directly to `self.email` and `self.create_date`. Since you don't have a `price` setter, I will make that a property without a setter, so that you can retrieve the price but not set it.